# To remove linux directories ending with build numbers

Tags: command-line

I have a path where there will be build directories copied, so i need to keep only latest 3 directories and delete others, not by date but with the latest build number.

If i have the following directories in the path /tmp

1.1.0000-021,
1.1.0000-005,
1.1.0000-018,
1.1.0000-004

I should be deleting 1.1.0000-004 directory in /tmp path as its the oldest directory.

I was trying with rm -rf /base/path -type d -ctime 4 , but this is based on latest file, not sure about getting oldest number to delete.

Comment: You do this with a script. What have you tried and where does it fail? This is not a "write my code for me" site.

Comment: "...and where does it fail"? And [edit your question](http://superuser.com/posts/810204/edit). All the relevant information should be in there, don't answer in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following chain:

**ls**: list files/directories

**sort -nr**: sort files/directories numerical, reversed

**tail**: leave from the list just the last $n (here:4) entries (if only 4  remain, the list will be empty)

for example:

```
ls | sort -nr | tail +5
```

Then take the files and delete them; (i.e. with xargs + rm)

Comment: Thanks Philip, this seems working  ls |sort -nr |tail -n +4 |xargs rm -rf

Comment: Glad i could help!